# It is possible to make an IPSEC VPN Bonding?

Tags: vpn, ssh-tunneling, tunneling, ipsec, bonding

I wanted to know if It is possible to bound two IPSEC tunnels ? I've already done a VPN bonding of SSH tunnels, but It will be better if I use IPSEC.